# Turning a single for loop into nested loops

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, loops, for-loop

I am trying to separate a single for loop into multiple loops. I was able to do it for turning a single loop into two loops as such:

```js
console.config({
    maxEntries: Infinity
});

// looping 0-100
let q = 100;
for (let i of [...Array(q % 10 === 0 ? q / 10 : (q - q % 10) / 10 + 1).keys()]) {
  for (let j of [...Array(((i + 1) * 10 <= q ? 10 : q % 10)).keys()]) {
    console.log(i * 10 + j);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(I know it doesn't look too pretty)

I want to turn the same loop into 3 or 4 loops. How can I do this?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish with the above code

Comment: This looks like a really confusing way to do `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) console.log(i * 10 + j)`

Comment: You can easily split these loops further in the same way.

Comment: @Barmar How can I do it for all `q`? I tried `q / 10` for the `i` bound and `q%10 + 10` for the `j` bound but it doesn't give the correct values

Comment: @SumnerEvans The above code loops from 0 to 100, by first creating an array of [0, 1, .., 9], and for each i, constructing the actual number.

I must absolutely use arrays for the loop (I'm trying to recreate for loops in MongoDB aggregate framework), but for q > 100M, it uses too much memory. Instead I separate one loop into multiple ones, and let MongoDB deal with the numbers.

Comment: Just use `10` for the `j` bound, it's not dependent on `q`.

Comment: If you want to generalize, you can use `let stride = 10` and then `q/stride` is the `i` bound, `stride` is the `j` bound, and the formula is `i * stride + j`

Comment: @Barmar for `q = 25` it returns values 0-29

Comment: On the last iteration of `i` you need to special case the `j` bound. That's when you use `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating `i` and `j` both by 1, iterate `i` by the row size and start `j` from `i`.

```js
let q = 25;
let rowsize = 10;
for (let i = 0; i < q; i += rowsize) {
  for (let j = i; j < Math.min(i + rowsize, q); j++) {
    console.log(j);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Still can't wrap my head around how to make this into 3 loops

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a loop with *n* iterations into multiple nested loops, you'd want to find multiple values of which their product is *n*. like

```
100 = 10*10
100 = 10*5*2
//up to
100 = 5*5*2*2
```

and all combinations of these, like `5*5*4` or `25*4` or `25*2*2` ...

so the first step would be to find the prime factors for the number of iterations you want, to see what your options are.

```js
function* primes(limit) {
  yield 2;
  var i = 3,
    sieve = new Int32Array(Math.ceil(limit / 64)).fill(-1);
  for (; i * i <= limit; i += 2)
    if (sieve[i >> 6] & (1 << (i >> 1 & 31))) {
      yield i;
      for (var j = i * i; j <= limit; j += i + i)
        sieve[j >> 6] &= ~(1 << (j >> 1 & 31));
    }
  for (; i <= limit; i += 2)
    if (sieve[i >> 6] & (1 << (i >> 1 & 31)))
      yield i;
}

const iterations = document.querySelector("#iterations");
const factors = document.querySelector("#factors");

(iterations.oninput = function() {

  let v = iterations.valueAsNumber;
  if (isNaN(v)) return;

  let factors = [];
  for (let prime of primes(v)) {
    if (prime * prime > v) break;
    while (v % prime === 0) {
      factors.push(prime);
      v /= prime;
    }
  }
  if (v > 1 || factors.length === 0) factors.push(v);

  document.querySelector("#iterations-out").textContent = factors.join(" * ");
})();

(factors.oninput = function() {
  const numbers = document.querySelector("#factors").value.match(/\d+/g);
  if (!numbers) return;

  let pre = "  ".repeat(numbers.length) + "console.log(";
  let post = "0);";

  const iterations = numbers.reduceRight((factor, v, i) => {
    const padding = "  ".repeat(i);
    const w = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
    pre = `${padding}for (let ${w} = 0; ${w} < ${v}; ++${w}) {\n${pre}`;
    post = `${w} * ${factor} + ${post}\n${padding}}`;
    return factor * v;
  }, 1);

  document.querySelector("#factors-out").textContent = `// total = ${iterations}\n${pre}${post}`.replace(" * 1 + 0", "");
})();
```

```html
<label>numbers to factors: <input id="iterations" value="100" type="number" /></label>
<pre id="iterations-out"></pre>

<label>factors to loops: <input id="factors" value="10 10" /></label>
<em>(somehow sepetrated numbers)</em>
<pre id="factors-out"></pre>
```

The issue is if you have a number of iterations that is either a prime number or consists of (too big) prime factors.

Since I don't know enough about MongoDB aggregate framework and what exactly you're building, I can only suggest to replace one loop (nested or not) with two or more consecutive loops that contain better factors.

Like `127` -> prime can't be split exactly, but `63` `(3*3*7)` + 64 `(2*2*2*2*2*2)` works better.

```
for (let a = 0; a < 9; ++a) {
  for (let b = 0; b < 7; ++b) {
    console.log(a * 7 + b);
  }
}
// offset = 63;
for (let a = 0; a < 8; ++a) {
  for (let b = 0; b < 8; ++b) {
    console.log(a * 8 + b + 63);
  }
}
// total 127 iterations
```